# How to use sparklines in AG Grid with observablehq?

Tags: ag-grid, observablehq

A couple of months ago, I created an `observablehq` based `AG Grid` table with `sparklines`. Recently, the `sparklines` stopped working, and I am not sure why. Here is a [notebook](https://observablehq.com/@novotny1akub/ag-grid-with-sparklines) with an example that used to work, but is not working anymore. The third column, Rate of Change, is supposed to contain sparklines.

I previously loaded `AG Grid` with `AgGrid = require('ag-grid-enterprise/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.js')`, but this generates an error now so I changed it to `AgGrid = require('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-enterprise@25.2.0/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.js')`, which seems to be working for the grid, but does not render the `sparklines`. I do not know why the former require call no longer works. When I inspect the devtools, it says `AG Grid: Looking for component [agSparklineCellRenderer] but it wasn't found.` so apparently the sparkline module is not imported correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
AgGrid = require("ag-grid-enterprise@27.3.0/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.js")
```